# Calling local class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm trying to call a static method from a class called "JSON", however the import I'm doing already has this method. How can I call a local class?

I've tried this:

```
mypackage.subpackage.JSON.encode(param1)
```

In C # the above would work, but I do not know why in ActionScript below does not work.

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class Package extends ByteArray
{
    public function writeJsonObject(param1:Object) : void
    {
        this.writeUTF(JSON.encode(param1));
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method decode through a reference with static type Class

Comment: **(1)** Note that **Package** and **JSON** are a reserved keyword in AS3 language. Try changing names to `myPackage.as` and `myJSON.as` and see if error goes away... **(2)** Your error says method `.decode` is the problem here, but your shown code is doing an `.encode`. Is the error caused by something else later on? **(3)** Also what is `this.` supposed to be? Is it the class `Package` itself or some other external caller of the function (in another or Main class)? I mean is it needed? **(4)** How do you use the above code (eg: any **static** variables involved)? Maybe there's a better way...

Comment: I mean tell us what you're trying to achieve with your classes, show some code that demonstrates the problem, and we can try suggest a better way.

Comment: JSON doesn't have an encode function in AS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.stringify()`

```
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class MyClass extends ByteArray
{
    public function writeJsonObject(param1:Object) : void
    {
        this.writeUTF(JSON.stringify(param1));
    }
}
```

Reference: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Also worth noting the difference between `writeUTF` and `writeUTFBytes` to understand exactly what's getting written to your `ByteArray`